# Stocks: Where can I find a list of bankrupt/diluting stocks in the US?

Tags: stocks

I'm trying to find a list of bankrupt stocks, however I can't find any JSON APIs or any websites that provide that in a CSV.

I want a list of bankrupt stocks or stocks that are diluting that are still listed. Are there any indicators for stocks like this? I know for already bankrupt stocks, there's a `Q` at the end right?

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does "bankrupt/diluting stocks" even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only recommendation I have is to try the stock screener from Google Finance :

https://www.google.com/finance?ei=oJz9VenXD8OxmAHR263YBg#stockscreener